# How to use YN568EXIII for nikon as a master flash

Tags: nikon, flash

I bought a YN568EXIII for Nikon to use as a master for my YN568EX Speedlight. I have been having trouble figuring out how to use it as a master for my YN568EX.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: I don’t think anyone will answer until you say a little about what steps you have tried, and what problems you are having.

Comment: I see a [really cryptic note in the user manual](https://www.yongnuo.fr/wp-content/uploads/notices/YN-568EX-III_N_en.pdf#page=21) that the **YN-568EX III (II)** can be a master unit. I'm assuming that means it requires a firmware adaptation or has to be as second hardware version of the model in order to do optical master. The older YN-568EX units could only ever do slave modes, not master.  Generally, I say ditch Yongnuo and get Godox radio flash gear instead (e.g., a TT685 II-C and an Xpro-C). Yongnuo incompatibilities will drive you up the wall.